# Sorting floating numbers

Tags: c++, matlab, sorting, opencl

I have a list of normal vectors and I am calculating the scalar triple product and sorting them. I have compared the sorting in three different cases:

1. Using Matlab sort to find the largest absolute triple product values
2. Using `std::sort` function in C++ to get the product values for `std::vector`. Using doubles for triple products.
3. Using Radix sort in OpenCL C - converting the absolute floating values to unsigned integers and converting them back. I am using `cl_float` for triple products.

All of them give values which are different along with the different indices which causes problems in my algorithm. What is the problem in this case and how can I keep them consistent?

Comment: Precision issues maybe?

Comment: I am thinking of the same reason. Would conversion of all of them to be floats help?

Comment: Hmm, just a shot in the dark: May be `long double` helps?

Comment: But OpenCL cannot support doubles sadly. That will have to used in the final algorithm.

Comment: I was thinking that Matlab stores the data in doubles and that should correspond to the sort function in C++

Comment: `All of them give values which are different along with the different indices which causes problems in my algorithm`  Floating point computations can never be relied on for consistency.  So much so that even a for() loop that has floating point starting and ending conditions cannot reliably run a set number of times.  Expecting an algorithm to give the same results would be rather unreasonable, unless you rewrite it to use integer values.

Comment: CL 1.1 (and later) has the potential to support double. You need `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable` - of course, the hardware may not support that! But the CL standard does. Not that this really helps explaining why you get different order, unless the values are very close.

Comment: @Paul Hold on! Floating point arithmetic is predictable, reliable, and repetitive. It just happens that it's implementation is more complex than the integer one.

Comment: @Kahler - `Floating point arithmetic is predictable, reliable, and repetitive.`  If that's the case, then why is the OP having issues?

Comment: @MatsPetersson my hardware doesnt support double implementation

Comment: @shunyo (requesting some info before trying to answer) by `normal vectors` you mean theirs magnitude is bound to (nearly) one? Are they (each vector of the input) 3-dimensional binary32 float array? Like `{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}`? Do you mind if I came with something out that may be not very performance-wise but does calculate the Triple product? And finally, by Triple product you mean that one that goes `a * (b x c) `?

Comment: @Kahler Yes, you are correct. The normal vectors are unit vectors and yes, they are input as 3-D float32 arrays. The scalar triple product is a.(bxc). I would love to see something that can provide consistent results. Thank you

Comment: It seems unlikely that sorting is the issue, it's more likely that the  products are slightly different due to using different math. Even if the array is using the same floating point representation in all 3 cases, the internal floating point representation used for math operations can still be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem at hand:

- Calculate the scalar triple product of 3 3-dimensional vertices, being each component of each vector represented as `binary32 float`.
- Being able to tell if a result of that calculation is greater than other result of that calculation.

So far so good, but if we directly apply the formulae to the vectors, some bits may be lost in the operations and we will be unable to discern two results. As @rcgldr pointed out, sorting is not the problem, the precision is.

One solution to floating point roundoff problems is to increase the number of bits, that is, use `double`. You said you have no `double`, so let's do it ourselves: perform the whole calculation in an array of `unsigned char` as long as we need.

Okay, okay, practical considerations:

1. The input is made of normalized vectors, so the length is no greater than one, that implies no component is greater than one
2. The exponent of a `binary32` float ranges from -127 (zero, denormals) to 127 (or 128 for infinity), but all components will have exponent from -127 to 0 (or else they would be greater than one).
3. The maximum precision of the input is 24 bits.
4. Scalar triple product involves an vector product and an scalar product. In the vector product (which will happen first) there is subtraction of results of multiplication, and in the scalar product there is a sum of results of multiplication.

Considerations 2 and 3 tells us that the whole family of input components can be fit in an fixed-point format of size 127 bits for offsetting plus 24 bits for the mantissa, that's 19 bytes. Let's make it 24.

To be able to fully represent all possible sums and subtractions, one extra bit suffices (in the advent of carryover), but to fully represent all possible multiplication results, we need double the number of bits, so it resolutes that doubling the size is enough to represent the vector multiplication, and tripling it will make it enough for the next multiplication in the scalar product.

Here is a draft of class that loads a float to that very huge fixed point format, keeping the sign as a bool flag (there is a helper function `rollArrayRight()` that I'll post separately, but hopefully it's name explains it):

```
const size_t initialSize=24;
const size_t sizeForMult1=initialSize+initialSize;
const size_t finalSize=sizeForMult1+initialSize;
class imSoHuge{
public:
    bool isNegative;
    uint8_t r[finalSize];
    void load(float v){
        isNegative=false;
        for(size_t p=0;p<finalSize;p++)r[p]=0;
        union{
            uint8_t b[4];
            uint32_t u;
            float f;
        } reunion;
        reunion.f=v;
        if((reunion.b[3]&0x80) != 0x00)isNegative=true;
        uint32_t m, eu;
        eu=reunion.u<<1; //get rid of the sign;
        eu>>=24;
        m=reunion.u&(0x007fffff);
        if(eu==0){//zero or denormal
            if(m==0)return; //zero
        }else{
            m|=(0x00800000); //implicit leading one if it's not denormal
        }
        int32_t e=(int32_t)eu-127; //exponent is now in [e]. Debiased (does this word exists?)
        reunion.u=m;
        r[finalSize-1]=reunion.b[3];
        r[finalSize-2]=reunion.b[2];
        r[finalSize-3]=reunion.b[1];
        r[finalSize-4]=reunion.b[0];
        rollArrayRight(r, finalSize, e-(sizeForMult1*8)); //correct position for fixed-point
    }
    explicit imSoHuge(float v){
        load(v);
    }
};
```

When the class is constructed with the number `1.0f`, for example, the array `r` have something like `00 00 00 00 80 00`, notice that it is loaded to the lower part of it, the multiplications will ~roll~ the number accordingly  to the upper bytes, and we can then recover our float.

To make it useful, we need to implement the equivalent to sum and multiplication, very straight-forward, as long as we remember we can only sum arrays that have been multiplied the same number of times (as in Triple product) or else theirs magnitude would not match.

---

One example where such class would make a difference:

Consider the following 3 vectors:

```
float a[]={0.0097905760, 0.0223784577, 0.9997016787};

float b[]={0.8248013854, 0.4413521587, 0.3534274995};

float c[]={0.4152690768, 0.3959976136, 0.8189856410};
```

And the following function that calculates the triple product: (hope I've got it right haha)

```
float fTripleProduct(float*a, float*b, float*c){
    float crossAB[3];
    crossAB[0]=(a[1]*b[2])-(a[2]*b[1]);
    crossAB[1]=(a[2]*b[0])-(a[0]*b[2]);
    crossAB[2]=(a[0]*b[1])-(a[1]*b[0]);
    float tripleP=(crossAB[0]*c[0])+(crossAB[1]*c[1])+(crossAB[2]*c[2]);
    return tripleP;
}
```

The result for `fTripleProduct(a,b,c);` is `0.1336331`

If we change the last digit of the fisrt component of `a` from `0` to `6`, making it `0.0097905766` (which have a different hexadecimal representation) and call the function again, the result is the same, but we know it should be greater.

Now consider we have implemented the multiplication, sum, and subtraction for the `imSoHuge` class and have a function to calculate the triple product using it

```
imSoHuge tripleProduct(float*a, float*b, float*c){
    imSoHuge crossAB[3];
    crossAB[0]=(imSoHuge(a[1])*imSoHuge(b[2]))-(imSoHuge(a[2])*imSoHuge(b[1]));
    crossAB[1]=(imSoHuge(a[2])*imSoHuge(b[0]))-(imSoHuge(a[0])*imSoHuge(b[2]));
    crossAB[2]=(imSoHuge(a[0])*imSoHuge(b[1]))-(imSoHuge(a[1])*imSoHuge(b[0]));
    imSoHuge tripleP=(crossAB[0]*imSoHuge(c[0]))+(crossAB[1]*imSoHuge(c[1]))+(crossAB[2]*imSoHuge(c[2]));
    return tripleP;
}
```

If we call that function for the two above versions of the vectors, the results in the array differ:

```
0  0  0  4 46 b9  4 69 39 3f 53 b8 19 e0  ... 

0  0  0  4 46 b9  4 85 93 82 df ba 7d 80  ...
```

And they differ after the precision of a `binary32 float` indeed, meaning that if we cast that array back to float, it will be the same float, but if we compare the arrays, we can tell which one is greater.

---

The put that reasoning to the test, I've made a full working example, that you can compile and run right away with `-O3 -Wall -std=c++11` in GCC, or equivalent on another compiler and will output:

```
Using class: second result is greater
casting to float:
first reasult: 1.336331e-001
second result: 1.336331e-001
as floats, the results are the same: 1.336331e-001
```

The source code is here (working fine on Ideone):

[Source Code on IDEONE C++11 code](http://ideone.com/C5RCM2)

If you have not migrated to C++11, the code compiles and run in C++98 if you define the exact-width types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `int32_t` yourself.

---

How to use it?

Simple call the function `tripleProduct` with your inputs and compare the results using the provided overload comparators operators, you can also cast the class `imSoHuge` to float (after the calculation of triple product) using the provided overload cast operator.

You can provide an array of that class and comparators to any sorting algorithm.

---

Conclusions and considerations:

Notice that a float multiplication is now performed as a multiplication of two 70+ bytes long array, that means hundreds of time more clock cycles, plus the sums, comparisons etc, this shall be thousands of time slower, but hey, it's exact.

The whole design of the algorithm is to work with normalized vectors (there is some room here, as I don't know the precision or your normalization procedure), but it will all overflow and be meaningless with most 'greater-than-one' vectors.

You can easily cap the array of the result to as many bytes you wish, if keeping all that array in memory is too much. Very few cases will produce results diverging after ~12bytes

I haven't stress-tested everything, like denormals, and corner cases, there is some comments in the code to the critical points.

and of course:

You can easily improve everything, I was just willing to share the reasoning =)

---

[Source code again](http://ideone.com/C5RCM2)

Main reference:

[Single-precision floating-point format (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Wow! I am thoroughly impressed with the answer. The explanation is detailed and succinct. Thank you.

Comment: =D All I wanted to hear. The things we do for love ♥. Hope it's ultimately useful.